# NoMethodError: undefined method "delete_prefix" String class (Ruby 2.4.1)

Tags: ruby, ruby-2.4

I'm using the latest Ruby (version 2.4.1)

I see there's a method `String#delete_prefix` as defined in
https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/String.html#method-i-delete_prefix

But in `irb`, this method doesn't exist for some reason:

```
2.4.1 :030 > c="_abc_xyz"
=> "_abc_xyz"
2.4.1 :031 > c.delete_prefix("_")
NoMethodError: undefined method `delete_prefix' for "_abc_xyz":String
from (irb):31
from /Users/jonsmith/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
2.4.1 :032 >
```

What's going on here?!

(The above can be achieved by `c.gsub(/^_/, '')`, but I'm wondering why `delete_prefix` and `delete_suffix` don't exist contrary to Ruby documentation.)

Comment: The commit was merged on June 19. Ruby 2.4.1 was released in March, 3 months before `String#delete_prefix` was even written. So, it cannot possibly be in there. There seems to be a bug in Ruby-Doc's build scripts. Note: it always helps to check the documentation that comes with the Ruby you have actually installed instead of looking on third-party sites.

Comment: After doing `rvm install ruby-head`, the methods `String#delete_prefix` and `String#delete_suffix` are available.  Thanks